# Error in printing SSRS Report

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reporting-services, printing, modal-dialog

I have a SSRS report which is open in a javascript modal popup window.

Report renders without any problem, but when i try to print the report using print button it gives me the following error:

> An Error occurred when trying to get the current window

Please give me your opinions on this

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue regarding the print button in modal windows which has been reported [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/586182/report-viewer-control-v10-modal-window-print-error-an-error-occurred-trying-to-get-the-current-window).

The answer from Microsoft is:

> Thank you for your feedback. We have reviewed this issue.
>   Unfortunately, this does not meet the release criteria for the next
>   release.
>
> We will resolve this as Won't Fix.

Here is what you could do:

- Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> instead of the print button
- Use a non-modal popup
- Submit another [connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/) item

Comment: Thanks Sebastien. At least now I know that its impossible

Answer (score 0):

Also, the Report Viewer print button doesn't seem to work cross browser. If you're open for an alternate solution, you can render your report as a PDF unto another tab. I would rather hide the Print button from the tool bar. Let the PDF preview allows the end user to the printing.

```
            rpt1.ShowPrintButton = false;
```

The click:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] bytes = rpt1.ServerReport.Render("PDF");

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.End();
    }
```

In aspx:

```
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Print" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="frmMain.target='_blank';"/>
```